# intent to google maps from webview

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I have a webView in Android, and I open a html webpage in it. There are several link to google maps and i want to intent to native apps. I have set any other link to my host file will intent to native apps. I have tried several way other but also failed. Any idea?

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView

            if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("googledrive.com")) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="maps.apple.com"
                android:pathPattern="/.*"
                android:scheme="http" >
            </data>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code....!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


/*
 * 
 * THis class create for browser handaling.
 * 
 */
public class SimpleBrowser extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText url;
    WebView ourBrow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simplebrowser);

        ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);

        ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient());
        try {
            ourBrow.loadUrl("http://admstest.netau.net/ADMS/View/LoginView.php");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

XML Layout..........!

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etURL"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            tools:ignore="TextFields" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bGo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:text="Go"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <WebView  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wvBrowser"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

AndroiMainfest.xml

```
 <activity
        android:name="viewActivity.SimpleBrowser"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIMPLEBROWSER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```